# Set Session with usernames value

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I try to query the current username which is logged in and set the value to a Session. Finally, it seems to be working but in browsers console I get the following Exception: `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`

```
Template.dashboard.helpers
  'setUsernameToSession': ->
    user = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId())
    Session.set 'username', user.username
```

It is my fist question here and I'm a Meteor novice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper is running before your user has fully logged in. You can avoid the error by adding a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) like so:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers
  'setUsernameToSession': ->
    Session.set 'username', Meteor.user()?.username
```

However, you really shouldn't be doing this in the first place because helpers should be side-effect free - see the 'overworked helpers' section of [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Instead you can just use `Meteor.user()?.username` anywhere in your code that needs the username, and in a template you can use `{{currentUser.username}}` without the need for a helper. Both examples are reactive so there is no need for a `Session` variable.

---

In your specific case, you want to alert the user whenever she logs in. One way to do that is with an [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) which you can place anywhere in your `client` directory:

```
Tracker.autorun (c) ->
  # extract the username
  username = Meteor.user()?.username
  if username
    # replace this with something better
    console.log "Welcome back #{username}!"
    # stop the autorun
    c.stop()
```

This should be a more robust solution than using a session variable because:

1. Session variables get erased on refresh or after closing the browser.
2. It will work across browsers/machines - I assume you want to track that the user logged in anywhere, rather than tracking that a particular user logged on again with the same browser.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and detailed answer. I'm right there with you. But how you proceed if the user has already logged out and you want to display a welcome back message like `Welcome back, David!` if the user reopens the page. Because Meteor is reactive session is the only way to implement such a function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I updated the answer with a simple suggestion for how to accomplish that. Let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thankee! Great blog by the way, many helpful information!